# Drupal - Form in block, content in page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a custom form with some content that depends on some variables. At this time, those variables are hardcoded but I want the user to be able to choose them in a block. I know how to make a block in drupal but how can I connect both the block (form) and the content page?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to make usage of [hook_block_configure()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_configure/7).

Comment: That is for the block configuration itself. In this case, I have already the page with a hook_menu but I want to show a block with a form for inputs to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Print the form from your block:

```
print drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_register_form'));
```

Where parameter is form_id, of course.

Comment: Thanks MilanG. I don't understand what you mean. My hook_block_view has $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('MYFORM_form'); That form has a textfield and a submit button. That textfield is the variable I want to inject in the function for the page render. So... that code is not what I need, I think.

Comment: My idea is not to use block to display form, but to print form directly from you page template.

Comment: That is a solution. If I go that way, how can I show the form in the page and the results below?

Comment: Please edit your question and add as much as possible details about what you want to obtain, as at this moment I got confused.

Comment: Try it out. This call should render all form elements.